# Подскажите, как приравнять верхний и нижний регистр?

Tags: javascript

Пробовал к переменной country присвоить метод toUpperCase и toLowerCase и приравнять их

```
let country = prompt("введите название страны");
if (country == "USA" || country == "Great Britain"){
        alert("Английский язык");
    } else if (country == "Germany"){
        alert("Немецкий язык");
    } else if (country == "France"){
        alert("Французский язык");
    } else {
        alert("Указанной страны нет в списке");
    }
```

Comment: Ну покажи как пробовал

Comment: Хотя в принципе понятно, если привести к верхнему регистру, или нижнему, то будет или FRANCE или france, но никак не France

Comment: Есть такая волшебная вещь -console.log , позволяет узнать, что хранится в переменной.

Answer (score 0):

```
let country = prompt("введите название страны");
let countryUpper = country.toUpperCase();
if (countryUpper == "USA" || countryUpper == "GREAT BRITAIN"){
    alert("Английский язык");
} else if (countryUpper == "GERMANY"){
    alert("Немецкий язык");
} else if (countryUpper == "FRANCE"){
    alert("Французский язык");
} else {
    alert("Указанной страны нет в списке");
}
```

---

Вариант попроще:

```js
let countryMap = {
  'USA': 'Английский язык',
  'GREAT BRITAIN': 'Английский язык',
  'GERMANY': 'Немецкий язык',
  'FRANCE': 'Французский язык',  
};
let country = prompt("введите название страны");
let countryUpper = country.toUpperCase();

console.log(countryMap[countryUpper] || "Указанной страны нет в списке");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let country = prompt("введите название страны");
    country = country.toLowerCase();
    switch (country) {
        case "usa":
        case "great britain":
            alert("Английский язык");
            break;
        case "germany":
            alert("Немецкий язык");
            break;
        case "france":
            alert("Французский язык");
            break;

        default:
            alert("Указанной страны нет в списке");
            break;
    };
```